# Final Fantasy 15 Archive missing from Main Menu

Tags: ps4, final-fantasy-15

When I go to the main menu for some odd reason I don't see the archive option under photos, this is what I see (the red circle is where the archive option is supposed to be):

[image]

Is there any reason why that might be missing?

Comment: Please refine your question. You do not see "archive" under photos for what purpose, enable what features, and you listed your question for Final Fantasy IV (4)....

Comment: Okay I've added more detail and updated the header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your copy of FF15 updated?

The Archives Menu was part of an update and if you haven't updated you wont be able to get to it.

Advice: Save your game. Ensure you are updated to the latest version of FFXV.

If not, update the game and then check again for the "Archive" menu.

I'm updated to 1.03 and have the Holiday DLC (free) installed.

[image]